# ActiveReports Printing Issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, activereports

I have generated ActiveReports pdf file with paper size 240 mm*305 mm[Bigger than A4]. We are printing the same report several times on continuous rolling sheet. The first page is printing correctly but from the second page, printable data is not in the same position. It is slightly moving upwards as shown in the image.

[image: sample]

Comment: Can you please specify the version of ActiveReports you're using and the type of report (Section/Page/RDL)? And the method you're using to print - from the viewer or code? Thanks

Comment: Version is ActiveReports9. It is a section report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a PDF is generated the page size is final and will not be repaginated when it is printed to the printer.   Based on your description, the PDF is a different size from the printer paper-size.    Once the PDF file is generated, all the printing is handled by your PDF application and the printer,  ActiveReports code is no longer involved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We will check with printer settings.